# Typescript: referencing subclass properties in superclass?

Tags: javascript, typescript

E.g.:

```
class Super {
  getProp(key: ???) {
    return this[key];
  }
}

class Sub extends Super {
  foo = 123;
}

const sub = new Sub();
console.log(sub.getProp('foo'));
```

Is it possible for the type of `key` to be "any property on the subclass"?

Comment: In your example you pass the value `'foo'` this would mean that the paramter `key` should be of type `string` i.e. `getProp(key: string)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `keyof this`

```
class Super {
    getProp(key: keyof this) {
        return this[key];
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    foo = 123;
}

const sub = new Sub();
console.log(sub.getProp('foo'));
console.log(sub.getProp('something')); // Error
```

Comment: Do you know if this is possible with `static` methods/properties? E.g. `static props: (keyof this)[] = []` would cause `A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.`

Comment: Don't think you can do it with `static`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define all the **keys** in sub class .. so it didn't throw error

```
class Super {
    getProp(key: keyof this) {
        return this[key];
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    key1 = 123;
    key2= '123';
    key3 ='hello';
}

const sub = new Sub();
console.log("key key1 & value =>",sub.getProp('key1'));
console.log("key key2 & value =>",sub.getProp('key2'));
console.log("key key3 & value =>",sub.getProp('key3'));
```

[image: output]